# istringstream - why isn't there a reset function

Tags: c++

The following is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::istringstream f;

    f.clear();
    std::string s("line1");
    f.str(s);
    std::string line;    
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    f.clear();     // must both clear() and str()
    f.str(s);
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My question is around these 2 line:

```
f.clear();     // must both clear() and str()
f.str(s);
```

Calling `f.str(s)` is problematic for me, but I find that just calling `clear()` ends up the `getline()` call afterwards does not read anything.

I looked at istringstream interface and do not see any reset kind of function, but just ask in case I miss something.

The reason why `str()` does not work for me - my class takes istream* as input, it does not have the real originals which could be a file or a string.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem.  What is the actual problem that you are having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear what it is you want to accomplish, but if you want to read the same stream again, an `istringstream` is an `istream`, and `seekg` works in the normal way.

This prints "line1" twice:

```
int main() {
    std::istringstream f;
    f.clear();
    std::string s("line1");
    f.str(s);
    std::string line;    
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    f.clear();
    f.seekg(0);
    while (std::getline(f, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset an *istringstream*, you need to call.

```
f.str("")
```

`f.clear()` is only to clear the error flags, not the actual 'content'.